# AngularJS Asynchronous calls with multiple databases and a save not in the correct order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I am quite confused at this whole JavaScript and its asynchronous calls.

It is a simple function really, or so I thought. I have a function that searches two different databases for a site id. If the site id cannot be found in db1, then it has to search db2 and save that site in db1.

1. Pass in a siteId
2. Search siteId in db1
3. Cannot find siteId in db1, search db2
4. Get the site from db2
5. Save the site in db1
6. Search db1 for the site again
7. Return the site to display to UI

My code below:

```
var xSite='';
function getSite(siteId) {
        xSite = siteId;
        var predicate = Predicate.create('siteId', '==', siteId);
        return EntityQuery.from(entityNames.site) //db1
            .where(predicate)
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (data.results.length == 0) {
                logError('Site Not Found!');
                //staticDb is a separate datacontext
                staticDb.getStaticSites(xSiteId).then(function(data) {
                            addSiteToOrg(data[0], 8);
                            save().then(function() {
                                common.$timeout(function() {
                                    return EntityQuery.from(entityNames.site)
                                        .where(predicate)
                                        .using(manager).execute()
                                        .then(querySucceeded2, _queryFailed);
                                }, 1250);
                            });
                        });
            } else {
                activeSite = data.results[0];
                if (activeSite.devices.length == 0) {
                    getSystemsAtSite(activeSite);
                }
                return activeSite;
            }

            function querySucceeded2(data) {
                activeSite = data.results[0]; //this value is correct
                if (activeSite.devices.length == 0) {
                    getSystemsAtSite(activeSite);
                }
                return activeSite;
            }
        }

    function addSiteToOrg(site, org) {
        var newSite = manager.createEntity('Site', {
            siteId: site.siteID,
            siteName: site.name,
            country: site.country
        });
    }

    function save() {
        return manager.saveChanges()
        .then(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(result) {
            logSuccess('Saved data', result, true);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Save failed: ' +
           breeze.saveErrorMessageService.getErrorMessage(error);
           error.message = msg;
           logError(msg, error);
           throw error;
          }
     }
```

What actually happens is something out of chaos: (Numbers same as above)

- 1. Pass in a siteId
  2. Search siteId in db1
  3. Cannot find siteId in db1, search db2 -> timeout->
     **7. Return the site to display to UI**
  4. Get the site from db2
  5. Search db1 for the site again
  6. Save the site in db1

After the Save is done, I'm not sure where it goes, because it did not go to the chained function.

I'm not sure how to save this site before I have to go find it and then return it to the UI. I have tried using q, defer, timeout, something... anything! but I can't seem to get it in the correct order of action.

Why is it going out of order? 
Shouldn't the ".then()" execute after save?

Edit 1: The return from querySucceed2 goes no where. The function already returned undefined before it ever executes the addSiteToOrg() or save().

Comment: Is this using Angular's $q? I think in Javascript the function always returns the last return value, but to make it more readable, change to `return save()`. Then, the result of `save` will be consumed by the next `.then`

Comment: but I don't want the return value of save(). I need the site value from db1. Using AngularJS v1.2.23

Comment: Did any of the answers below address your question?

Comment: I'm still working on getting the answers to work out. It'll probably take me another day or two to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was such a fun question that I had to try it ... or something close.

I wrote a mocha/chai test for it that hits the breeze DocCode sample Web API which has two controllers that happen to access the same database (Northwind).

I made two simplifying assumptions:

1. That the `siteID` is the key property for the "Site" type (just as `CustomerID` is the key for the "Customer" type).
2. The metadata are the same for the entities in question (here "Customer", for you it is "Site") in BOTH data sources.  I'm imagining that db2 has the same structure as db1.

Here is the test that I wrote:

```
it("your example", function(done){
    var id = alfredsID; // testFns.wellKnownData.emptyGuid;

    var ds1 = new breeze.DataService({serviceName: 'http://localhost:58066/breeze/Northwind'});
    var ds2 = new breeze.DataService({serviceName: 'http://localhost:58066/breeze/NorthwindDto'});

    em.fetchEntityByKey('Customer', id, true /* search cache first; then go to server */)
        .then(firstQuerySuccess)
        .then(confirmResult)
        .then(done, done);  // test artifact; ignore in your code

    function firstQuerySuccess(data){
        var entity = data.entity;
        if (entity){  return entity; } // got it

        // not found; query again in second data source
        switchToDataSource2(em);
        var key = data.entityKey; // same key as before
        var promise = em.fetchEntityByKey(key, false /* only go to server #2*/)
            .then(secondQuerySuccess);
        switchToDataSource1(em); // immediately, before async call returns
        return promise; // from the second query
    }

    function secondQuerySuccess(data){
        var entity = data.entity;
        if (!entity){ return entity; } // can't find it in the 2nd source either; give up

        // although it was retrieved from DS2, it's actually new in DS1
        entity.entityAspect.setAdded();
        return em.saveChanges([entity])
            .then(function saveSucceeded (){ return entity; }, // we've got it; no need to refetch it.
                  function saveFailed (error) {
                      if (/duplicate/.test(error.message)) {
                          // it's already in ds1; race condition?; assume so and reverse the add
                          entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
                          return entity;
                      } else {
                          // something bad happened; remove from cache and forward the error
                          entity.entityAspect.setDetached();
                          return breeze.Q.reject(error);
                      }
                  });
    }

    function switchToDataSource1(em){
        em.setProperties({dataService: ds1});
    }

    function switchToDataSource2(em){
        em.setProperties({dataService: ds2});
        em.metadataStore.addDataService(ds2, true /*overwrite if found */);
    }

    // You would add your own success function to do what you want with the entity
    // Here we apply chai.js expectations to confirm that the entity is what we expected.
    function confirmResult(entity){
        if (entity){
            var key = entity.entityAspect.getKey();
            expect(entity.entityType.shortName).to.equal('Customer', 'EntityType is '+entity.entityType.name);
            expect(entity.entityAspect.entityState).to.equal(breeze.EntityState.Unchanged,
                    'EntityState is '+entity.entityAspect.entityState.name);
            expect(key.values[0]).to.equal(id, 'key is '+JSON.stringify(key));
        } else {
            expect(false).to.equal(true,
                    'Did not find entity with ID='+id+ ' in either data source');
        }
    }
})
```

### Observations

This "works" in the sense that **the code does exactly what I *want* it to do** ... which I hope is exactly what *you* want it to do. It does seem to me to follow the intended sequence that you described.

I'm hampered by the fact that I don't have two databases. The two data sources in this example actually refer to the same physical database. So I don't have a case where the Customer is in ds2 but not ds1. That means the entity with the id I seek is always either found in ds1 or not found in either of them

I can simulate an inability to find it in ds1 by commenting out the quick return in `firstQuerySuccess`

```
// if (entity){  return entity; } // got it
```

Notice that for this second query, I have to change the manager's `DataService` momentarily to DS2 (`switchToDataSource2`).  I do this only long enough for breeze to evaluate the query and fire it at the server. I immediately switch it back to DS1 (in `switchToDataSource1`) so that subsequent queries with this em are using DS1.  I only need DS2 for the length of time it takes to issue the query to the server.

Notice also that I ensure in `switchToDataSource2` that the `MetadataStore` in `em` is associated with BOTH DS1 and DS2. I'm leveraging the simplifying assumption #2 that I mentioned above.

Now the entity **is found** in the second data source.

I have to set it's state to "Added". *That's critical!* We retrieved the entity from ds2 in an unchanged state. But it doesn't exist in ds1 so we have to change its state to "Added".

Now I can save it to DS1.

**I DO NOT** have to re-fetch the entity after the save. I already have it in cache. So I can just return it when/if the save succeeds.

The final `.then(done, done)` is a testing artifact and *would not be part of your code*. Your code would actually do whatever is appropriate inside `confirmResult`.

In practice, the save always fails **for me** because the entity already exists in ds1 (remember, ds1 and ds2 actually map to the same database). That won't be an issue for you.

*Or maybe it could happen to you too!* It's always possible that another user looks for the same `siteID` at the same time and happens to save successfully to ds1 before you do. You'll have lost the race and you'll get the same "duplicate" error that I get.  I show how you might handle that in the `saveFailed` callback.

One final point: notice that **every promise call back returns either a promise or a value**. You must do that to keep the callbacks flowing. Otherwise, the chain is broken and the app seems to drift into space.

Only the final `confirmResult` callback neglects to return a value; and it shouldn't return a value or else the mocha test falls apart (don't make me explain). `confirmResult` will throw an exception if the entity fails an expectation ... and that's just fine.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hello Ward, thank you for taking your time to show an example. I still have a weird order of execution. In my case, after the first em.fetchEntityByKey, it returns to the controller for the UI where the function was called, but for some reason it says that the "then" function is undefined. (datacontext.getSite(siteId).then(function (data) { vm.site = data;}) After that, it goes to firstQuerySuccess. Do you have any suggestion on why?? (I am using john papa's hot towel template)

Comment: That usually happens when you forget to return the promise from `em.fetchEntityByKey` (or any promise-producing method). I make that mistake all the time.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding "return the promise from 'em.fetchEntityByKey'". Where am I suppose to return it? Using the code above, I'm not quite sure, unless the code above is missing the return the promise.

Comment: The code above is inside a test (the `it` method). There is no one to receive it so the promise returned from my `em.fetchEntityByKey` is not forwarded to a caller. But your controller would be calling into a method that wrapped this whole thing ... perhaps a method called `getSite()`. `getSite` should return the promise and so would be written `return em.fetchEntityByKey( ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use simplified function names since I don't know what `EntityQuery`, etc... exactly is

```
function getSite(sideId) {

  return search(db1, siteId)
    .then(function(data) {

      if (data.length > 0) return data;

      var fallbackSearchPromise = 
        search(db2, siteId)
          .then(function(data) {

            if (data.length === 0) return null;

            return save(db1, data);
          })
          .then(function(saveResult) {

            if (saveResult !== null) return null;

            return search(db1, siteId);
          });

      return fallbackSearchPromise;

    });
}
```